# $_SERVER['request_uri'] возвращение

Tags: php

Всегда ли `$_SERVER['request_uri']` в нулевом индексе возвращает `'/'`?
То есть возвращает строку вида - `'/pages/about'`, и на 0 индексе всегда слеш?

Comment: в этом и есть весь вопрос? Так то да, если надо можно и срезать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В нулевом индексе всегда будет лежать первый байт строки.
Т.е. для `$_SERVER['request_uri']` всегда слэш.